# How to check recyclerview is empty or not using dataSnapshot.hasChildren()

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am using firebasedatabase to show my data into recyclerview. I want to show simple toast when my recyclerview is empty and i am using `dataSnapshot.hasChildren()` for checking the database haschildren or not. here is code

```
  private void Geofireinit() {
    started = true;
    databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(("tracker"));
    GeoFire fire=new GeoFire(databaseReference);
    GeoQuery geoQuery = fire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(20.887715, 77.757623), 50);
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {


            Log.e("id", key);


            getkeys(key);


        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onKeyExited: ");




            for (int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++)
            {
               Log.i("tte",String.valueOf(arrayList.get(i).getText()));
               if (key.equals(arrayList.get(i).getText())) {
                   arrayList.remove(i);
                   adapter.notifyItemRemoved(i);

               }
               if (arrayList.size()==0)
               {
                   Log.i("exited",String.valueOf(arrayList.size()));
               }

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {


        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}

ArrayList<Mylist> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
private void getkeys(String key)
{
    myref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("buses").child(key);
    myref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists())
            {

                Mylist mylist=new Mylist();
                mylist.setText(dataSnapshot.child("text").getValue().toString());
                arrayList.add(mylist);
                adapter=new Adapter(MainActivity.this,arrayList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.i("chaadad", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.hasChild("buses")));
            }

            if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren())
            {
               // do something
            }else
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

when data is available the dataSnapshot.hasChildren() giving true value but when no data available else condition is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#public-long-getchildrencount)

```
if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0)
{
    // do something
} else
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

> **Update:**

check the else condition for the .exists() for empty list

```
if (dataSnapshot.exists())
{

    Mylist mylist=new Mylist();
    mylist.setText(dataSnapshot.child("text").getValue().toString());
    arrayList.add(mylist);
    adapter=new Adapter(MainActivity.this,arrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.i("chaadad", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.hasChild("buses")));

} else
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: This code also giving same output and i also use `if(arraylist.isEmpty)` only when data is available this works but when data is not available both if else not work

Comment: @prototype86 please check update section at the answer

Comment: Yes when data is available if condition is triggered but but when data is not available else is not executing. I do not know what is happening

Comment: Sir i have check also this not working else statement not working

Comment: `if(dataSnapshot.exists())` is working fine when data is available but when data is empty the else condition is not executing

Comment: @prototype86 maybe `onCancelled()` is called for some error .. you can a log in it to check

Comment: `onCancelled()` not giving any error i have checked

Comment: Sorry my mistake the `onkeyEntered()` not calling when no key is available i added some condition and it is working fine thank you sir for supporting to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215979/discussion-between-prototype86-and-zain).

Answer (score 1):

```
   ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(!snapshot.hasChildren()){
            // db has no children
        }

        // OR this way
        if(snapshot.getChildrenCount() == 0){
            // db has no children
        }

        // OR this way
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            // db has no children
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Sir i do not want to use `addValueEventListener` because it gives me duplicate values

Comment: Ohhh sorry, If I miss led you.

Comment: No sir it is okay